# Squares in the set $\{\sum_{j=1}^m j^2: m\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

Are there infinitely many squares in the set $$\{\sum_{j=1}^m j^2: m\in\mathbb{N}\} ?$$

Comment: No, only for $m=1$ and $m=24$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36702/the-sum-of-perfect-squares

Comment: This is the well-known square pyramid problem whose only solutions are $m=1$ and $m=24$, although the proof is not immediate.

Comment: See also: [The sum of the first $n$ squares is a square: a system of two Pell-type-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74265) (and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/74265)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have $\sum_{j=1}^m j^2 = \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}6$. Hence, the question reduces to finding integral points on the elliptic curve:
$$y^2 = \frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}6.$$
Turning it to Weierstrass equation with integer coefficients, we get:
$$(72y)^2 = (12x)^3 + 18 (12x)^2 + 72 (12x).$$

For many curves, integral points can be readily found by SageMath, and in this case we are lucky:

```
sage: EllipticCurve([0,18,0,72,0]).integral_points()
[(-12 : 0 : 1), (-9 : 9 : 1), (-8 : 8 : 1), (-6 : 0 : 1), (0 : 0 : 1), (6 : 36 : 1), (12 : 72 : 1), (288 : 5040 : 1)]
```

So, the only solutions are $m=\frac{0}{12}=0$, $m=\frac{12}{12}=1$, and $m=\frac{288}{12}=24$.